# Set start time for Stopwatch program in C#

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I want to write a simple stopwatch program, I can make it work with the following code

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch ss = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch { };
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text == "Start")
        {
            button1.Text = "Stop";

            ss.Start();
            timer1.Enabled = true;

        }
        else
        {
            button1.Text = "Start";

            ss.Stop();
            timer1.Enabled = false;

        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            int hrs = ss.Elapsed.Hours, mins = ss.Elapsed.Minutes, secs = ss.Elapsed.Seconds;
            label1.Text = hrs + ":";
            if (mins < 10)
                label1.Text += "0" + mins + ":";
            else
                label1.Text += mins + ":";
            if (secs < 10)
                label1.Text += "0" + secs;
            else
                label1.Text += secs;


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ss.Reset();
       button1.Text= "Start";
       timer1.Enabled = true;

    }
```

Now I want to set a custom start time for this stopwatch, for example I want it not to begin count up from 0:00:00 but to start with 0:45:00
How can I do it, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new instance of [System.TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan) with the initial value of 45 minutes as per you example. Than add the value of the stopwatch to it [TimeSpan.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add). Conveniently the [Stopwatch.Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx) is of type System.TimeSpan already.

Than use string formatter to print the formatted time into the label. I think one of the other answers already shows how to do that. Otherwise here are some good references on how to format a TimeSpan instance [TimeSpan.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx) or using a [custom formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287).

```
var offsetTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(0,45,0).Add(ss.Elapsed)
```

Answer (score 22):

Stopwatch does not have any methods or properties that would allow you to set a custom start time.

You can subclass Stopwatch and override ElapsedMilliseconds and ElapsedTicks to adjust for your start time offset.

```
    public class MyStopwatch : Stopwatch
    {
        public TimeSpan StartOffset { get; private set; }

        public MyStopwatch(TimeSpan startOffset)
        {
            StartOffset = startOffset;
        }

        public new long ElapsedMilliseconds
        {
            get
            {
                return base.ElapsedMilliseconds + (long)StartOffset.TotalMilliseconds;
            }
        }

        public new long ElapsedTicks
        {
            get
            {
                return base.ElapsedTicks + StartOffset.Ticks;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a lot of code just to be able to offset the timer. I think adding an offset at the time when the value of the stopwatch needs to be displayed is a better approach. If reuse is important add the code as extension method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: @BigT: Really?  A lot of code?  I posted an implementation.  It might be slightly longer than your extension method, but it encapsulates the desired behavior.  And it's *really* not a lot of code.  And it solves the original question.

Comment: Note that properties are not overridden, but hidden using _new_ keyword.
 It means that they will only be used only if your variable type is exactly MyStopwatch. E.g. if you decide to store it in List<Stopwatch> then you will end up end up accessing original Stopwatch type properties and getting value without offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter the start time, but you can modify it after the Stop() and no one is the wiser.

A quick Google search: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.start(v=vs.90).aspx

A minor modification:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        
        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes + 45 , ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

Result:

> RunTime 00:45:10.00
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

A little more research on your part will help you immeasurably as a developer.

Comment: The math should be done using the Add function built into TimeSpan. This code will fail often. Any time the stopwatch has minutes >= 15 then the time format is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

is the offset fixed or variable?

In either case, have it as some member variable or const for the class and just add it.

```
private TimeSpan offset = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45);
```

Then just change your tick to include it:

```
var combined = ss.Elapsed + offset;
int hrs = combined.Hours, mins = combined.Minutes, secs = combined.Seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

- additional SetOffset() method
- additional initialization with offset;
- overrides all of needed methods
- **have the same class name, so no need to change your project code**

.

```
using System;

public class Stopwatch : System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
{
    TimeSpan _offset = new TimeSpan();

    public Stopwatch()
    {
    }

    public Stopwatch(TimeSpan offset)
    {
        _offset = offset;
    }

    public void SetOffset(TimeSpan offsetElapsedTimeSpan)
    {
        _offset = offsetElapsedTimeSpan;
    }

    public TimeSpan Elapsed
    {
        get{ return base.Elapsed + _offset; }
        set{ _offset = value; }
    }

    public long ElapsedMilliseconds
    {
        get { return base.ElapsedMilliseconds + _offset.Milliseconds; }
    }

    public long ElapsedTicks
    {
        get { return base.ElapsedTicks + _offset.Ticks; }
    }
}
```