# How to set start time for Stopwatch in C#?

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch, elapsedtime

I want to set a `StopWatch` starting time from a specific time.

I calculate a `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(frames*128)` (each frame shown every 128 milliseconds).

Than I proceed as follows:

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TimeFrame*128);
//e.g. 3762*128ms = 00h:08m:01s:5630ms

var offsetTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0,0,timeSpan.Minutes,timeSpan.Seconds,timeSpan.Milliseconds).Add(_timeStopWatch.Elapsed);

_timeStopWatch.Start();
```

I used a methond specified by @Big T [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681457/set-start-time-for-stopwatch-program-in-c-sharp). However the `StopWatch` seems to start from 00:00:00. How should it be done properly?

Comment: Stopwatch is used for measuring time duration elapsed. Why would you want to start it from a specified time. Actually it starts from the current time and that's how you measure elapsed time normally.